# How do I have Core Data managedObjects created from JSON file and have them persist between app launches?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a bunch of NSManagedObjects that are created from a JSON file online. Currently, I am creating them all each time the app launches (not ideal).

What is the best way to check to see if the objects are already there before I try to create them?

if I do `[self saveContext]` it seems to work, but as I don't know how to check if they are already loaded, it ends up duplicating everything.

Obviously, I am relatively new to Core Data and seem to be missing a key concept.

[EDIT] After reading more and more about where and when to load this many objects into Core Data, it looks like pre-loading the data is the best option for me (the data is static and will likely only be update a few times per year).

I chose not to use the "find or create pattern" as I assumed it would be more expensive given the number of objects that need to be checked/created and would like to save learning about background queues for next time ;)

I was then having trouble getting the sqlite file to work, and solved it by saving the context after *each* object was created, rather than once after all the objects were loaded.

Comment: do a find or create pattern as specified by apple

Answer (score 1):

The way this is handled usually in my experience is via one of the two options:

1. You first check if the item exists, and if it does, then you update it, else insert it.  Here's a sample of what I have used in the past for a vouchers model:

   ```
   Voucher *newObject = nil;

   NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Voucher"];
   request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"voucher_id = %@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"voucher_id"]];
   NSError *error = nil;
   NSArray *matches = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

   if ([matches count] == 0 ){
       newObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Voucher" inManagedObjectContext:context];
       newObject.number = [json_dictionary objectForKey:@"number"];
       newObject.valid_from = [json_dictionary objectForKey:@"valid_from"];
       newObject.valid_to = [json_dictionary objectForKey:@"valid_to"];
   }
   else {
       newObject = [matches lastObject];
       newObject.number = [json_dictionary objectForKey:@"number"];
       newObject.valid_from = [json_dictionary objectForKey:@"valid_from"];
       newObject.valid_to = [json_dictionary objectForKey:@"valid_to"];
       newObject.voucher_id = [json_dictionary objectForKey:@"voucher_id"];
   }
   return newObject;
   ```
2. The other way is to select all, put into an NSOrderedSet, and then run a comparison, and only insert if not in the set.

If you look at "Core Data Performance Optimization and Debugging" on this page  https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/ , it's got a great explanation of this

Answer (score 0):

Ray Wenderlich has a detailed tutorial on Core Data that show you how to do it step by step: (make sure to turn on Google Translate)

In response to your question under comments, here it is:

1. create a new file and choose to create datamodel (under Core Data)
2. add your entities - entities are what you declared as class data models. Note that I have Location, Marker, and Village because I have created those as classes (Location.m/.h, etc)]
3. Add attributes (properties) associated with those entities.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOUvF.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AJGZ.png

Comment: Or brush up on my Korean!  Unfortunately it is a bit hard to comprehend: "This is on OS X to import data from any data source to create a simple console app that back into Core Data store data store do they move to iOS project horse. Cool is that?"

Comment: I found the English version of the same article, and says there are 2 methods for doing this: 1. Fill in Core Data on startup from external source, and 2. Provide pre-filled in SQLite database. The article goes on to demo #2, but I want to know how to do #1.

Comment: I updated the response to your question above. if not clear, can you upload your code somewhere on github and I can help

Comment: The trouble was not loading the objects into Core Data, but trying to avoid loading them in each time if they already existed.

Comment: Without seeing your code, its hard to see what you're doing wrong. However, I have Ray Wenderlich's book, the iOS Apprentice ($54). There are 4 tutorials in this book and the third tutorial goes in depth with Core Data. There is also source code and you could compare what you're doing wrong. (http://www.raywenderlich.com/store/ios-apprentice). The 3rd tutorial itself is around 280 pages long and it will definitely help you with Core Data.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't worked on it before, the learning curve might be a bit steep. But one good way is to use RestKit.

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#core-data